# How to save files to Android /system directory?

Tags: android, file, root, save

I am writing an application that will copy files from its assets directory to the Android's /system directory.

I feel that I am getting close to achieving this, but I am not quite there. Here is the strategy that I have attempted:

First, I tried to change the permissions of the /system directory by:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock4");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod -R 777 /system");
```

Second, I tried to write a file to the /system directory.

I read that by remounting the directory, I could write files to it. Indeed, this seemed to work with a terminal. But in the application, I couldn't figure out how to make sure each command was completed before execution of the next one.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume there is a return value from the `exec()` method that you should be checking to see if the execution worked fine.

But I think you've got several mistakes in your attempts to execute this series of commands:

- `su` can only influence its own process and child processes. You execute it with no arguments, so it does nothing. The next `exec()` method starts over from scratch with the exact permissions of your process, not the elevated privileges you might expect.
- Your `mount(8)` command doesn't seem right: you're not saying which mountpoint to manipulate. (Don't forget that a device may be mounted in multiple locations.)
- Your `chmod(1)` call also doesn't run with privileges *and* sets permissions way too open. Perhaps you don't care about security on your device, that's fine, but be certain that that is what you want.

I believe your `mount` command should look more like:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c \"mount -orw,remount /system\"");
```

And I believe your `chmod` command should look more like:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c \"chmod 777 /system/fonts\"");
```

Again, be certain you understand the consequences of allowing all users on the system privileges to write to any file that other users can execute.

Comment: Thanks for advice, but what would you suggest should be the minimum permission setting for merely writing a file? Also, could a potential solution be to change the permissions back to normal as soon as the file is written?

Comment: Seriously don't chance the permissions! If you are executing as root the permissions don't matter anyway.

Comment: But, wouldn't the user of the app be the only one able to access this? How would anyone else get to this? Do you think resetting the permissions is a good idea?

Comment: @Michael: it really depends what you're trying to accomplish. _Why_ do you want every user on the system to be able to modify everything under `/system`? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: My app is trying to use a root feature, basically just write a file to a read-only directory. In this case, /system/fonts. I only require the bare minimum permission to do this task.

Comment: Then `chmod -R 777 /system` is definitely far too open. `chmod 777 /system/fonts` is significantly better, but only if you're interested in making that directory writable for everyone for the long term. Best would be to use `su` to add or remove specific files from that directory exactly when you want to perform the operation _and never change the permissions at all_.

Answer (score 1):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec
```

will return a `Process`, from the process class, you can

```
getInputStream  or getOutputStream or getErrorStream
```

from these method, you can get the command execute result, you can check it to ensure command
execute right or wrong.