# Android: how to update system package programmatically

Tags: android

I'm implementing an updateService in Android. It is an Android service with system privilege. It checks package updates from server, and perform the update. For normal packages under /data/app,  the updateService just needs to invoke PackageInstaller to do the job. But system packages under /system/app can't be updated this way. I just want to know, how can the updateService update the system packages? Especially, itself is an system package under /system/app, it should be able to update itself.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can remount the disk to achive the priviligies you want,  [here is some info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720885/how-to-save-files-to-android-system-directory).